# Python 3*3 grid layout with letters

Tags: python

I want to get a 3*3 grid with randomly assign letters.

I tried the following code

```
import random
def Random_Alpha():
    l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    return l[random.randint(0,25)]

nums = []
for i in range(3):
    nums.append([])
    for j in range(1, 4):
        nums[i].append(print(Random_Alpha()))
print("3X3 grid with letters:")
print(nums)
```

I got the following output

```
T
B
T
S
R
K
A
T
S
3X3 grid with letters:
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

But I need to get following output

```
T | S | A
---------
B | R | T
---------
T | K | S
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`. Change `nums[i].append(print(Random_Alpha()))` to `nums[i].append(Random_Alpha())`. I hope that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
def Random_Alpha():
l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
return l[random.randint(0,25)]

nums = []
for i in range(3):
    nums.append([])
    for j in range(1, 4):
       nums[i].append(Random_Alpha())
print("3X3 grid with letters:")
for i in range(3):
    print(*nums[i],sep='|')
    print('-----')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this line:

```
nums[i].append(print(Random_Alpha()))
```

To this:

```
nums[i].append(Random_Alpha())
```

The `print` function returns `None`, so at the moment you are always trying to append `None` to the list, instead of a letter.

By the way, to get a random letter from your list, you can use `random.choice(l)`. [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) returns a random item from a non-empty sequence, so using it means you don't have to worry about specifying the list indices.

Answer (score 2):

With Jack Taylor's answer, you can use `string.ascii_uppercase` instead of manually creating a list of strings.

This code also provides the formatting if that's what you want

```
import random
import string

nums = []
for i in range(3):
    nums.append([])
    for j in range(1, 4):
        nums[i].append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
print("3X3 grid with letters:")
output = [f"{n1} | {n2} | {n3}" for n1, n2, n3 in nums]
print(*output, sep="\n---------\n")
```

Output:

```
3X3 grid with letters:
T | Q | Z
---------
L | H | R
---------
W | B | C
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before the problem is the `print`. And BTW you overcomplicated the solution. Here a clean one:

```
from random import choices
from string import ascii_uppercase


def print_grid(n=3):
    for i in range(n):
        print(" | ".join(choices(ascii_uppercase, k=n)))
        if i != n-1:
            print("-" * (4 * n - 3))
```